# Node.js API filtering

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I have an endpoint like: 
channels/:id/albums -> returns all albums for a specific channel

What I would like to have is: How can I for ex filter the result, let say I want only albums that have specific field, or limit the num of rows returned.

How Can I achieve this in Node.js with Express?
A sample code which I have righ now looks like:

```
new Album().where('channel_id', '=', req.params.channel_id).fetchAll()
    .then(function (album) {
        res.json({error: false, status: 200, data: album});
    })
    .otherwise(function (err) {
        res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
    });
```

Thank you,

Comment: Is this a hypothetical API? Your own? Or a service? It makes a difference to how this *should* be implemented

Comment: This is a real example...

Comment: @Paystey I disagree, it should be implemented in the best possible way...everytime.

Comment: eh? are you saying I was suggesting implementing the worst thing? @LulzimFazlija what is the API? Does it already give you options for filtering and limiting? Is there documentation? If the API can't do these  things, then you'll have to code them yourself. All very different solutions

Comment: @Paystey no I'm making the point that whether this is hypothetical or real is irrelevant.

Comment: Hypothetical APIs have all the features you want. Real ones don't. If it's a 3rd party API that doesn't have filtering support then you have to filter on the client after you've got all the data.

Comment: @Paystey you are talking about the underlying storage provider, I am referring to this solution in Node/Express given that's what the question asks. However, I am beginning to think that the question is more about the underlying storage provider rather than Node/Express at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append them as query string parameters and then check for them in your Express route. For example, if your request was `channels/12345/albums?maxResults=200` then you should be able to read that value from the `query` object in the request.

```
app.get('channels/:id/albums', function(req, res) {
    // req.query.maxResults will be 200
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to read the parameters from the URL, but what I was asking, was a more general answer, like how to make the filtering more general, let say I have this value 200, what would I do now? make a seperate function to show limit number of rows, or let say someone gives ?name=album1, should I make a seperate functions also to search from albums where name = album1?

Comment: @LulzimFazlija that's completely dependant on the your stoage provider. I am beginning to think that this question isn't about Node/Express at all and more to do with the underlying storage (which you make no mention of).

Comment: What do you mean by underlying storage?, This API is made using Express in Node.js

Comment: can you give me an example of how would I achieve a case like:
channels/:id/albums?fields=name

to show only name attribute for every albums returned

Comment: @LulzimFazlija you are clearly querying a data store i.e. `new Album().where(...).fetchAll()` - if your question is regarding this then you need to be more specific with what lib/storage you are using.

Comment: yes I am quering this data from Mysql data storage using bookshelf ORM for node.js, and it works, returns me the album with the given id, but what would I want more is: let say I want to filter now this result with filtering technique, like channels/:id/albums?name=album4, to give me only result with the album name=album4

Comment: @LulzimFazlija that's a *completely* different question to what your original question was asking hence why my answer was written as is.

Comment: what you doing in your answer, is just u are reading the value of a given param in the URL, but not demostrating what I was looking for, like example of filtering the result depending on the query string

Comment: @LulzimFazlija that's because your question was *misleading*. You asked about was how you could get extra filtering on an existing Node/Express route - you didn't mention anything about then applying these to an underlying data source. Also, have you read the [docs](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-where) on Bookshelf.js? There are *tons* of examples of how to do what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you James for the given link :)

Comment: I would just want to vote up your answer, but cannot :s, since I do not have 15 reputations yet